# Decrypt .SWF File in Java

Tags: java, flash, encryption, file-io

I am working last couple of hours to decrypt swf file, [I am following this Code](https://gist.github.com/instcode/1509527)  but when I try to run this code I get this Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Here is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileTest decrypter = new FileTest();
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("game.swf");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) inputFile.length());
            inputStream.read(buffer.array());
            decrypter.handle(buffer, new File("output.swf")); //**gives Exception**
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The goal is to read `game.swf` encrypted file and decrypt in `output.swf`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are not adding all the function and static methods of that class. Try to add it like the file code all this methods with their current code. I delete all the code because there was a lot of input but this thing to work You need all the this five methods in your main class with the code of course.

```
public static void decompress(byte[] data, File outputFile) 

public void unpack(ByteBuffer buffer, File outputFile)

private void handle(ByteBuffer buffer, File outputFile)

private ByteBuffer removeNonce(ByteBuffer buffer)

private ByteBuffer decrypt(ByteBuffer buffer)
```

Comment: I have all these five methods in code but when I run this program I get an exception.

Comment: Check if the File is not null then if you have this 5 methods,

Comment: input file or output?